What is the significance of the divine hidenness of God?
I understand that God created humans and hid His presence from them; humans cannot see God but can indirectly interact with Him through whispers, visions and dreams.
Is there any significance as to why God hid His dwelling and His hosts from man?
Scripture talks about a veil that is set to cover the spiritual world from the physical world and that when Jesus returns this veil will be lifted and nothing will be hidden from man.  Why did God place this veil?
Paul talked about a veil that covers the human heart that leads it away from the knowledge of Jesus Christ
2 Corinthians 3:14-16

Even to this day when Moses is read, a veil covers their hearts. But whenever anyone turns to the Lord, the veil is taken away."

This could also mean that there is a veil that separates the physical world from the spiritual world and angels can go through it, why did God fix it?

Your first two sentences seem to imply that God and his angelic host have a physical and substantive existence which is somehow obscured from men's eyes seeing that physical form. Did you mean to imply that or am I mis-reading it. ?

@NigelJ, I will ask ye another question and if you answer I will answer yours. Is the body of the risen Jesus Christ spiritual or physical or both?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Can you put a few Biblical references for the veil?  That will improve your question.

@GratefulDisciple, sure.

Behold my hands and my feet, that it is I myself: handle me, and see; for a spirit hath not flesh and bones, as ye see me have. Luke 22:39.

@NigelJ, but he dwells among spirits now for heaven is the home of spirits who include God and the angels. How do you respond to this?

My response was already given above and it still stands. The Lord rose bodily, as he indicates. And ascended bodily. And will return bodily. Scripture is very clear on this.

@NigelJ, but he sits at the right hand of God who is a spirit and talks to him, so if a physical Jesus can be in a spiritual realm then it means there is a veil between the two worlds

The veil is rent in twain from the top to the bottom, in the death of Christ. 'He is the One Mediator between Deity and humanity - humanity Christ Jesus' (literal). He is the One 'come near'. And He gives Another Comforter. It is yourself who is making distance.

@nigelJ, that was the physical veil, just like there is a physical temple there is also a spiritual temple so for a physical veil there is a spiritual veil

. . . . .  and, of course, Stephen looked up stedfastly into heaven, and saw the glory of God, and Jesus standing on the right hand of God once the heavens were opened. Which, I would say, answers the question.


Having therefore, brethren, boldness to enter into the holiest by the blood of Jesus, by a new and living way, which he hath consecrated for us, through the veil, that is to say, his flesh; And having an high priest over the house of God; Let us draw near with a true heart in full assurance of faith, having our hearts sprinkled from an evil conscience, and our bodies washed with pure water. - Hebrews 10:19-22

The significance of the Divine hiddenness of God is that it is the product of sin in the flesh.  Because all of us inherit the sinful flesh of Adam we are separated from God and God is thus hidden.  God did not hide from Adam, but Adam hid from God.
The Son of God took the sin of the world into his sinless humanity, He became sin, and offered it once for all of us.  He entered into the presence of God with His own blood to consecrate for us a way through the veil of sinful flesh. That way is by faith
The Father is increasingly less and less hidden from His children, from those who have been shown Him in Jesus. One day they shall all see him in full and not die but rejoice.

The significance of God being hidden is contained within the creator-creature distinction. By hiding himself, God reminds us that we are temporal beings who are not ultimately equal with him.
Further, God’s hiddenness exudes the performances of his grace. By hiding his power and majesty, they become more noticeable by us when they are obvious. If God incarnated himself in the wombs of virgins all the time, we may lose the significance of such an act.
Also, God’s hiddenness furthers the beauty and mystery of the incarnation of himself as a human being. By coming to Earth and showing himself as one like us, God makes a significant bridge between the hidden and seen (see Ratzinger’s discussion in Introduction to Christianity for a more detailed explanation of this idea).
Finally, apart from all notions of significant symbolism, God’s hiddenness is simply a consequent of his ontology. As pure act and being itself, anything God creates must definitionally be limited in some manner such that it is distinct from him. Because of this, we simply cannot grasp what it is like to be God, even if God were to heighten our perceptions ten-thousand fold. In this way, God always remains hidden from us in some capacity.

Is Jesus in spirit or flesh for at the right hand of the Father?

Good answer.  May I add Eleonore Stump's observation in one of her Closer to Truth interview videos that God could have written in the sky in giant letters "I am here.  Think about it." but that would be abusing an inherently imbalance of power.  Rather, God comes to man in the form of tortured and abused human person, so people's pride are lowered to want to receive grace from Jesus as God.  Which is why as imitator of Christ, we are told to turn the other cheek (when appropriate) and to repay violence with kindness and compassion.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany can you please rephrase your question? I think you may have mistyped what you meant to say.
